# Characterisation of Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, normal-distribution

The following Proposition is from Da Prato and Zabczyk's "Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions":

> **Proposition 2.5**. A measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is of the form $\mathscr{N}(0,q)$ for some $q \geq 0$, if and only if, for arbitrary independent real valued random variables $\xi$ and $\eta$ with law $\mu_\xi = \mu_\eta = \mu$ and numbers $\alpha, \beta$ such that  $\alpha^2+\beta^2=1$, we have the law $\mu_{\alpha \xi + \beta \eta} = \mu$.

($\Rightarrow$) direction is easy as we already know $\xi$ and $\eta$ follow normal distribution independently. How should I proceed the other direction? The book suggests to use characteristic functions. Take the characteristic functions of $\alpha \xi + \beta \eta$ we have
\begin{equation}
\varphi_\mu(t) = \varphi_{\alpha \xi + \beta \eta}(t) = \varphi_{\xi}(\alpha t) \varphi_\eta (\beta t) = \varphi_\mu(\alpha t)\varphi_\mu(\beta t)
\end{equation}
How should we deduce that $\varphi_\mu$ has the form of Gaussian? Thank you for any hint or suggestion!

Comment: Hey, I know this is super old now, but would you consider un-accepting md5's answer? It is not complete at all, and completely ignores the hard part of the problem. I think my answer is complete, but I do not except you to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\ph{\varphi}$I will use $\ph(t)=\int e^{itx}\mu(dx)$ to denote the characteristic function of $\mu$. We are given that
$$
\forall \alpha,\beta\in \mathbb R:\quad \alpha^2+\beta^2=1\implies \phi(t)=\phi(\alpha t)\phi(\beta t)
$$

The following statements hold for all  $t\in \mathbb R$.

**Step 1**: $\phi(-t)=\phi(t)$.

> *Proof:* Take $\alpha=-1,\beta=0$.

**Step 2**: $\phi(t)$ is real.

> *Proof:* $\overline{\phi(t)}=\overline{\int e^{itx}\mu(dx)}=\int \overline{e^{itx}}\mu(dx)=\int e^{i(-t)x}\mu(dx)=\ph(-t)=\ph(t)$.

**Step 3**: $\phi(t)> 0.$

> *Proof:* Taking $\alpha=\beta=1/\sqrt{2}$, we get $\ph(t)=\ph(t/\sqrt{2})^2$, immediately implying $\ph(t)\ge 0$. To get strict inequality, we apply this relation $n$ times, yielding $$\phi(t)=\phi(t/(\sqrt 2)^n)^{2^n}.$$ Since $\lim_{t\to 0}\phi(t)=1$ (true for all characteristic functions), there exists $n$ large enough so $\phi(t/(\sqrt 2)^n)>0$. For that $n$, the above implies $\phi(t)>0$.

**Step 4**: $\phi(t)=\exp(-ct^2)$ for some $c\ge 0$.

> Define
> $$
> f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb C\\
> f(t)=\log \ph(\sqrt{t})
> $$
> Because of steps $2$ and $3$, the range of $\ph$ over the domain $[0,\infty)$ is in the domain of $\log$, so this is well-defined. The functional equation for $\phi$ translates into this equation for $f$:
> $$
> \alpha^2+\beta^2=1\implies f(t)=f(\alpha^2t) + f(\beta^2 t)
> $$
> Now, for any $v,w\in [0,\infty)$, we can let $t=v+w$, $\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{v}{v+w}}$, and $\beta=\sqrt{w\over v+w}$, and the above implies
> $$
> \forall v,w\ge 0: f(v+w)=f(v)+f(w)
> $$
> Therefore, $f$ satisfies a one-sided version of the Cauchy functional equation. Since we also know that $f$ is continuous, being a composition of the continuous functions $\sqrt{\cdot}, \ph$ and $\log$, we conclude that $f(t)=ct$ for some $c\in \mathbb R$. This immediately implies
> $$
> \forall t>0:\log \ph(\sqrt{t})=ct\implies \forall t>0:\ph(t)=\exp(ct^2)
> $$
> Finally, the fact that $\ph(t)=\ph(-t)$ allows us to extend the above to conclude $\ph(t)=\exp(ct^2)$ for all $t\in \mathbb R$. In order for this to be a valid characteristic function, we need $c<0$.

**Step 5:** Conclude $\mu$ is normal.

> *Proof:* This follows from the bijective correspondence between characteristic functions and distributions, and the fact that a normal distribution with mean zero, variance $\sigma^2$, has characteristic function $\exp(-(\sigma^2/2)t^2)$.

Comment: Really thank you for your answer! This is a nice argument considering the moments (I heard about Hamburger's theorem, but never thought it would be used here!) But I will give the green check to md5 because he/she gives an argument using char functions, which is more straightforward to me. Sorry about this!

Comment: @mathdoge Perfectly reasonable :)

Comment: How do we know that all moments exist?

Comment: @DominikKutek I see my proof is wrong now. From your comments, I understand that once you have proven $\mu$ has finite variance, then the fact that
$$
X\stackrel{d}= \frac{X_1+X_2+\dots+X_{2^n}}{\sqrt{2^n}}
$$
allows you to use CLT to conclude $X\sim N(0,q)$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Yes, exactly the argument I had in mind.

Comment: @DominikKutek Hey, not sure if you ever figured out how to fill all the holes in the proof (from the comments on the other answer, it seems like no), but I did figure it out in case you are interested.

Answer (score 2):

A posteriori, you know that you want to prove that $\varphi_\mu(t)=e^{-ct^2}$ for some $c\ge 0$ (either because you can somehow predict it, or because it is explicitly written in your statement). It motivates looking at $g(t)=\log \varphi_\mu(t)$ instead. Now, your observation can be written

$$g(t)=g(\alpha t)+g(\beta t),$$

for any $t$ and $\alpha^2+\beta^2=1$. In particular, for $\alpha=1/\sqrt{2}$, this gives for any $t$,

$$g(t)=2 g(t/\sqrt{2}).$$

Do you see what kind of function $g$ can satisfy this type of equality? (You can take derivatives.)

Comment: Could you give more hints? Of course exponential functions give such equality, but would there be any possibility? I thought I might obtain some ODE by differentiating, but it is not the case?

Comment: If $h(t)=g''(t)$, you can see that $h(t)=h(t/\sqrt{2})$ for all $t$, so that does not leave many choices for (continuous) $h$...

Comment: Thank you, I got it! I didn't realize the constant becomes 1 if we take the second derivatives.

Comment: How do we know that $g$ is differentiable?

Comment: @DominikKutek I think that's some assumption we need to make

Comment: No, we don't. It' possible to show that it follows from the statement that $\mu$ has second moment finite (it isn't that trivial) and with that it's actually simple use of CLT to conclude that $\mu$ is gaussian. However the characteristic equation $g(t) = 2g(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}})$ can be solved without assuming $g$ differentiable. Indeed, for $t \ge 0$ let $G(t) = g(t^2)$, then $G(2t) = 2G(t)$. Can you take it from there? Note that $G$ is continuous without any further assumptions because characteristic function always exists and is continuous.

Comment: @DominikKutek I believe that's where I got stuck previously. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: About abother approach concerning CLT or about solving this functional equation without assuming differentiability of characteristic function?

Comment: @DominikKutek About solving $G(2t) = 2G(t)$ for $G$ without assuming the differentiability

Comment: Actually, I'm not able to solve $G(2t) = 2G(t)$ without assuming differentiability at $0$, so I think that it is necessary here to firstly show that $\mu$ has finite second (or at least first) moment, which will imply differentiability of characteristic function.